# Who are in the background in this Avengers 2 poster?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

[image: Black Widow in Avengers 2]

Who are those robots jumping from the helicopter?

Comment: @TomSterkenburg I'm not one of the DV'ers, but I'll hazard a couple of guesses. A lot of users frown upon questions about future works (this question was two months before the release). It arguably shows little to no research on OP's part. But more importantly, this was one of a string of similarly themed, and generally low-quality questions asked by the same user in fairly rapid succession.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These robots are known as Ultron Bots, and act as the minions of Ultron, a sentient, malicious robot who appears to be the main villian of *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

These robots are created in his image, are subservient to him and act as cannon fodder for his foes, distracting and dividing anyone that would attempt to harm him. In effect, the Ultron Bots will be to Ultron what the Chitauri were to Loki in *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* - an army of beings under one leader.

Comment: He's not malicious. Just misunderstood.

Comment: @BBlake Exactly! He just wants to improve humanity by adding evolutionary pressure. He may be a *little* overzealous, too.